# Selecting a word based on transition matrix weights in python

Tags: python, numpy, text, transition, prediction

I am trying to select the likely next word based on the current word, using previous word pair occurrences as "weights". I am having trouble implementing `np.random.choice()` in the actual choice of the next word.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

texty = "won't you celebrate with me what i have shaped into a kind of life i had no model born in babylon both nonwhite and woman what did i see to be except myself i made it up here on this bridge between starshine and clay my one hand holding tight my other hand come celebrate with me that everyday
something has tried to kill me and has failed." 

# https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/50974/wont-you-celebrate-with-me

words = texty.split()

# Creating the text-based transition matrix

x = pd.crosstab(pd.Series(words[1:],name='next'),
            pd.Series(words[:-1],name='word'),normalize=1)

print(x)

# Selecting the next word based on the current word.
# https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

current = "and"

# this part isn't working--->
next = np.random.choice(current,1,current) # was "y"
```

I don't know how to refer to the transition matrix from here. I would like this choice to be based on the probabilities of previous occurrences. For example, the probability of "clay" following "and" is 33%.

Comment: What did you expect to be the resulting value of the `y` variable? You have to pass something to `np.random.choice` to give it something to *choose from* (it seems you should pass the list of words in this case).

Comment: y would just be the next word. How do I get a list of words and their weights from x to pass into random.choice?

Comment: You can pass an additional argument `p` to specify the probabilities. But you still need to write some logic on your own to implement the concept of "current"  and "next" word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is a Pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html).

You can access any of the columns of that DataFrame as if the column names were keys into a dictionary.

```
> print(x['won\'t'])
next
a            0.0
and          0.0
babylon      0.0
...
with         0.0
woman        0.0
you          1.0
Name: won't, dtype: float64
```

The column returns as a Pandas [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html).  If you select a column from the DataFrame (your transition matrix `x`), the `index` of the Series you select will be available words from the text, and the `values` will be their associated probabilities.  You can provide each of these to `np.random.choice` to get the next word, with probabilities weighted from your transition matrix.

```
> current_word = 'won\'t'
> current_column = x[current_word]
> next_word = np.random.choice(current_column.index,
                 p=current_column.values)
> print(next_word)
you
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the index call I was missing. I really appreciate it!!